# jsonschema ref as direct parent schema fields

Tags: schema, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have two json schemas:

```
//person schema
{
  "id": "/person",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {"type": "string"},
    "baseFields": {"$ref": "/baseFields"}
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}


//baseFields schema
{
  "id": "/baseFields",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "age": {"type": "string"},
    "hobby": {"type": "string"}
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

below object will pass 'person scema' validation:

```
{
    "name":"person1",
    "baseFields":{
    "age":"33",
    "hobby":"diving"
    }
}
```

***what I need is*** that below object to pass 'person scema' validation:

```
{
    "name":"person1",
    "age":"33",
    "hobby":"diving"
}
```

I need it because I have few fields that are relevant to few different schemas

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is inheritance. But there is no inheritance in JSON schema.

You could use the "allOf" keyword. But it has some gotchas. See [here](https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html#allof) for an example and more info (check the 3rd example that has "street_address, city and state" fields).

Also [check this answer in so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410216/json-schema-and-inheritance).

Comment: I saw in your firs link that they are going to publish a solution for inheritance: " it does not behave like inheritance in an object-oriented language. There are some proposals to address this in the next version of the JSON schema specification".  How can I now when this next version is going to be published?

Comment: I would add a comment to that answer.