# allow one of all based on the same base type

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have the following json schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "description": "schema validating people and vehicles",
  "definitions": {
    "base": {
      "properties": {
        "age": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "age"
      ]
    },
    "person": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/base",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "firstName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "lastName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "sport": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "firstName"
      ]
    },
    "vehicle": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/base",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "vehicle": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "price": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/person",
    },
    {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/vehicle",
    }
  ]
}
```

And i want it to validate against

```
{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "sport": "football", "age": 15}
```

and the following

```
{"type": "car", "price": 100, "age": 3}
```

I get the following error `JSON is valid against more than one schema from 'oneOf'. Valid schema indexes: 0, 1.`.

Why is it valid against more then one? (`firstName` is only defined in `person` and `type` is only defined in `vehicle`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON Schema doesn't support inheritance.
See:

- https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/348
- https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html
- [JSon schema and Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410216/json-schema-and-inheritance)